# Some Subdomains on a Multisite Install Not Found

Tags: multisite, login, user-access, subdomains, domain-mapping

I am running WordPress multisite and can't access some subdomains. I can access the main website and other subdomains.

According to [isup.me](http://isup.me/) these subdomains are up.

Any idea why this would happen?

#### I've tried

- Changing my DNS to Google DNS
- Restarting Computer
- Clearing Cookies

But nothing has resolved the issue.

Comment: When you say "I can't access some subdomains" -- What happens exactly? 404? Security warning? A redirect? Please provide more information regarding your troubles so we can better attempt to assist you.

Comment: Nope, just a normal Server not found error

Comment: Depending on what the subdomains are (can you give examples) they may be blocked by WordPress or your server. For instance, if you are trying to go to admin.domain.com or root.domain.com your server may have these reserved. We really need more info to help you out.